# Reusing code in Angular 2, RxJS -- repetitive code within Subscriber body

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

**Problem**

I'm using a couple of [`BehaviourSubject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) vars in Angular2 to get data from a service and update an Array in the controller.

The problem is all the respective `.subscribe()` functions carry out the same operations and I cannot find a way to reuse the code -- maybe passing a lambda function into the body of the `.subscribe()`?

It doesn't make sense to retype the same code again and again -- it impacts the readability of the component.

**Scenario**:

Updating a chart with data from different sources

```
this.catagoryASubject.subscribe(
        value => {
            // updating array and chart
            this.radarChartData.forEach((val, i) => { if (val.label == value.name) { this.radarChartData[i].data = value.data } });
        },
        err => console.log("error"),
        () => console.log("complete")
    );

this.catagoryBSubject.subscribe(
        // same code as in the above subscriber
    );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`let()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-letProto) operator to group common functionality of observable chains. It takes observable as input and returns an observable, so you could write:

```ts
function updateChart(observable: Observable<any>) {
  return observable
    .map(value => {/* do your thing*/})
 // .filter().switchMap().do() // whatever
    .catch(error => console.log("error"))
}
```

and then use it:

```
this.catagoryASubject.let(updateChart).subscribe();
this.catagoryBSubject.let(updateChart).subscribe();
this.catagoryCSubject.let(updateChart).subscribe();
```

I prefer to use `subscribe()` just as a trigger, and not do any processing work there. It's much *cleaner*, and you can easily switch to `async` pipe when you need to...

```
this.A = this.catagoryASubject.let(updateChart);

<div> {{ A |async |json }} </div>
```

Comment: I came here to give an answer, I just landed on a better one. Thanks @Sasxa !

Comment: Inside the function I cannot use `this` operator to reference other variables in the component. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `this.catagoryASubject.let(o => updateChart(o))` syntax